Iwconfig not working
Am a newbie to linux and i have installed nethunter on my redmi 12pro+ rooted. Am currently using Alfa awus036acs wifi adapter with rtl8812au/21au chipset and my adpater isnt recognized in iwconfig even though it shows in lsusb. I've installed its drivers even upgraded and updated everything but nothing seems to work. Ifconfig not showing even lspci is saying "cannot find any working access method". I'd really appreciate your help.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
